# delete a project (Cocos2dx)

Tags: android, windows-8, cocos2d-x

I have a problem to delete a project in my project folder. I always get the message "An unexpected error is keeping you from deleting the folder. error 0x80070091: The directory is not empty". So what should I do to delete that folder?

Windows 8

Comment: Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on Super User.

Comment: probably something is still being used inside the directory so it cannot be deleted.

Comment: is there a way how I can find out how to get to those directories? (sorry I'm a total beginner)\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it!

It's very simple. I downloaded a third-party tool called "Unloacker" and after installation I was able to delete every corrupted file on my PC including those project folders.

Link:http://www.emptyloop.com/unlocker/